# How can I obtain a list of String with the values with XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
    <result>
    <street>a</street>
    </result>

    <result>
    <street>b</street>
    </result>

    <result>
    <street>c</street>
    </result>
</results>
```

I want to obtain a list of string containing all the street values.

In my example it is:

```
[a,b,c]
```

With XPath I can write anything like:

```
//street
```

I tried anything like:

```
XpathParser.INSTANCE.evaluate(xml, expression);
```

But I can only obtain a single string, not a list of strings.

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: you get a `NodeList` back if you use standard XPath API in Java ...

Comment: here is the correct way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java

Comment: I have tried that, but i have not a XML as Document, but a variable String containing the xml

Comment: invalid xml. you can only have one root node in any given xml document

Comment: you are right, I updated my xml

Comment: @anubis you have to learn using Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html - as you can see, there are mutliple methods `parse`, one of them taking an `InputStream` as argument. Conversion of a `String` to `InputStream`? Well, use the search ...

Comment: Here is the xpath that you can use `string-join(//result/street/text(),",")`